# Error I can't see

Tags: scheme

```
(define (length2 item)
  (define (test item count)
  (if (null? item)
      count
     ((+ 1 count) (test item (cdr item)))))
    (test item 0))
```

Got this as error:

+: contract violation
  expected: number?
  given: (2 3)
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments.:

I don't understand what's wrong? I tried to make it iterative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with the way you're passing the parameters in the recursion, notice that `count` is the second parameter. This should fix it:

```
(define (length2 item)
  (define (test item count)
    (if (null? item)
        count
        (test (cdr item) (+ 1 count))))
  (test item 0))
```

It works as expected:

```
(length2 '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> 5
```